# Can't create text file through Gitshell

Tags: git, github

I can't create a text file in gitshell. I've been trying to add files using

```
git add filename.txt
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...is there something else I need to add?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
touch filename.txt
git add filename.txt
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but doesn't explain why it works. The `git add` command doesn't create a file; it adds changes to an existing file to the staging area. The `touch` command updates the last modified timestamp on a file, and *creates the file if it doesn't exist*.

Answer (score 1):

First, initialize a local repository in your workspace,

```
git init foldername
```

Then add, `git add filename.txt`